# How many boys should be selected?

Tags: probability-theory

A school has $545$ boys and $455$ girls. $200$ students are selected randomly in proportion to the number of boys and the number of girls for an interview. How many boys should be selected?

A. $91$
B. $109$
C. $140$
D. $100$

Comment: All the three question you've posted so far, are pure-problem statement questions without any work or attempt. Read this before you post your next question: [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803).

Comment: Since this is a multiple choice question, it can be answered without much calculation. There are more boys than girls in the school, therefore there must be more boys than girls in the selected group. That eliminates two of the four answers. There are clearly less than twice as many boys as there are girls. This eliminates another answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Set up a proportion of the number of boys to total number of people and set it equal to the proportion of the boys picked and 200 people picked.

$\frac{545}{1000}=\frac{x}{200}$